$SU(3)$ color charge
Is the color charge the Noether charge due to the "global" $SU(3)$ symmetry of the QCD Lagrangian, or is it due to the "local" symmetry of the QCD Lagrangian?

It should be in your text. The QCD lagrangian, locally SU(3) symmetric, is also, a fortiori, globally SU(3) symmetric. The color charge is the Noether charge of this global symmetry.
In fact, you may add an extra  gluon mass term preserving the global symmetry, but violating the local (gauge) symmetry. Since it involves no derivatives, the above Noether charge results the same.
